# Access table import from csv only getting half the columns

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to import a csv file into access as a new table. For some reason it's not importing all of the columns. I'll note that there are 11 more columns in the excel, including the status and owner columns plus 9 more that also didn't make it into the table. It consistently excludes the same columns, though I can't see why it would exclude those specific columns.

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "TempMODBranch"
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TempMODBranch_Import", "TempMODBranch", sPath & "TempMODBranch.csv", True
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a vb.net question?  The code looks more like vba.  While share a lot of the same syntax, vb.net and vb6 are quite different

Comment: I think you're right, must've typed in vb and misclicked.

Comment: What does your import specification (`TempMODBBranch_Import`?) look like? Are all the fields there and the correct type?

Comment: @MarkMoretto I believe that is it. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkMoretto Caught me at end of day, but I wonder if you could help more. I'll note there wasn't anything in saved imports, but using the following query I did see an incomplete import spec.

SELECT
MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName,
MSysIMEXColumns.FieldName,
MSysIMEXColumns.Start,
MSysIMEXColumns.Width,
MSysIMEXColumns.SkipColumn
FROM MSysIMEXColumns
INNER JOIN MSysIMEXSpecs
ON MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID = MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecID

ORDER BY MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName,
MSysIMEXColumns.Start,
MSysIMEXColumns.Width;

Comment: I did a proper import via the wizard and saved the spec as the same name. But the results of the above query stayed the same, and it's still using the incorrect one.

Comment: Hi, sorry.  If you're still working on this, did you just use default settings with the wizard?  What are the ID and Name fields (the ones with single quotation marks)?  Did you let access add a primary key?

Comment: @babno if it's a csv file, can you try creating a spec sheet using a text file import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following

```
SELECT MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID, MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName
FROM MSysIMEXColumns INNER JOIN MSysIMEXSpecs ON MSysIMEXColumns.SpecID = MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecID 
ORDER BY MSysIMEXSpecs.SpecName, MSysIMEXColumns.Start, MSysIMEXColumns.Width;
```

I identified the specID it was using (72 for me). I then selected everything from MSysIMEXColumns

```
Select * from MSysIMEXColumns where specID = 72
```

and directly edited/added values as required.